# Handling of missing IP address values

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I'm using the following function to convert IP address to an integer value:

```
def convertIpToInt(ip):
    return sum([int(ipField) << 8*index for index, ipField in enumerate(reversed(ip.split('.')))])
```

The function works fine, but can't handle the missing values, I've filled those values with 0.

But, as 0 can't have a split function, it runs into error.

Also,I want to apply this function to all the columns of a data frame but, have to apply separately for each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most general is specified what values is returned if fail function with `try-except` statement:

```
def convertIpToInt(ip):
    try:
        return sum([int(ipField) << 8*index for index, ipField in enumerate(reversed(ip.split('.')))])
    except:
        return 0
```

If want also handle missing values:

```
def convertIpToInt(ip):
    try:
        if pd.notna(ip):
            return sum([int(ipField) << 8*index for index, ipField in enumerate(reversed(ip.split('.')))])
        else:
            return 'missing'
    except:
        return 0
```

If need apply function for some columns:

```
cols = ['col1','col2','col3']
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(convertIpToInt)
```

If need apply function for all columns:

```
df = df.applymap(convertIpToInt)
```